# Load and Parse a portion of External HTML

Tags: dom

I want to extract(parse) a portion HTML document from an external website using php

For example: To extract news  from yahoo, i tried using SimpleHTML DOM Parser from [sourceforge](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

```
<?php
$url="http://news.yahoo.com/einsteins-brain-now-interactive-ipad-app-071441969.html";
include('simple_html_dom.php');  
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$xxx=$html->find('title')->innertext; 
echo $xxx;
?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

---

Then I tried to echo the loaded html

```
<?php
$url="http://news.yahoo.com/einsteins-brain-now-interactive-ipad-app-071441969.html";
include('simple_html_dom.php');  
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
echo $html;
?>
```

Now I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function innertext() on a non-object in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 1688

---

I also tried using DOMDocument() through file_get_contents()

```
<?php
$url="http://news.yahoo.com/einsteins-brain-now-interactive-ipad-app-071441969.html";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
// echo $content works perfect

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$jjj=$doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
echo $jjj;
?>
```

This throws up a very long list of Warnings. So let me just copy paste the first 10 alone

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 166 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 166 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 256 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 256 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag
>   fb:login-button invalid in Entity, line: 256 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 275 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 287 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 292 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 311 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Attribute
>   class redefined in Entity, line: 325 in
>   /home/a1234bc/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 37

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using the Object-oriented way as shown in the manual:

```
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string
$html->load('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');

// Load HTML from a URL 
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com/');

// Load HTML from a HTML file 
$html->load_file('test.htm');
```

Got rid of the error and got my script working when I switched to the Quick way as shown in the manual:

```
// Create a DOM object from a string
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');

// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
```

After this `$html->find` worked just fine!

The PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser manual can be found here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

DOMDocument/SimpleXML are designed for parsing XML not HTML. You would need to use file_get_contents to get the HTML into a string and then using string manipulation functions to get the portion you need. [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) would be a good place to start.

Comment: OP uses "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" and links to it. And as you've probably seen in the FAQ, [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/927408)